# F# Exception Not Being Caught Correctly

Tags: exception, f#

I have an F# exception that it is not being caught in the correct catch block.

Here's the relevant code:

```
exception ConfigFileVersionIncompatabilityException of string

[<XmlType("config")>]
type Configuration() = class

    let thisVersion : string = "1.0"
    let mutable fileVersion : string = thisVersion

    [<XmlAttribute("version")>]
    member x.FileVersion
        with get() = fileVersion
        and set v = if v <> thisVersion
                    then raise (ConfigFileVersionIncompatabilityException(String.Format("Was expecting version {0} but read version {1}.", thisVersion, v)))
end


module FilterFileFunctions =

    let sampleConfigFilename = "sample.filters"

    let readConfig (file : string) =
        try
            use xmlDoc = new StreamReader(file) in
                let s = XmlSerializer(typeof<Configuration>)
                s.Deserialize(xmlDoc) :?> Configuration |> Success
        with
        | ConfigFileVersionIncompatabilityException(s) ->
            String.Format("Failed to read the configuration file: \"{0}\";\nThe following reason was given:\n{1}", file, s)
            |> Failure
        | ex ->
            String.Format("Failed to read the configuration file: \"{0}\";\n{1}", file, ex)
            |> Failure
```

The problem is that the `ex` catch block catches the `ConfigFileVersionIncompatabilityException` exception, where it should be caught by the first block.

I tried to use `:? System.Exception as ex` instead of just `ex` and it still behaved the same.

Am I missing something?

[Edited 1 minute after initial post to remove irrelevant code.]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When an exception occurs during the deserialization, the `Deserialize` method will catch it and wrap it inside `InvalidOperationException`. This means that you need to chatch `InvalidOperationException` and then analyze the `InnerException` property to get to your user-defined exception.

```
try // ..
with 
| :? InvalidOperationException as invOp ->
   match inv.InnerException with 
   | :? ConfigFileVersionIncompatabilityException as e -> 
     printfn "%s" e.Data0
   | _ -> // generic handler
| e -> // generic handler
```

The `Data0` property exposes the value carried by the exception (I used it, because you cannot access it easily in the pattern matching when using `:?`). However, you can avoid the ugly nesting of `match` expressions (and the duplication of generic handlers) using active patterns:

```
let (|InnerException|) (e:exn) =
    e.InnerException

try // ..
with 
| InnerException(ConfigFileVersionIncompatabilityException s) -> 
   printfn "%s" s
| _ -> // generic handler
```

Comment: It works! I really should have caught that the exception was wrapped in another one from the message it displayed. Ah well. I'll have to look more into active patterns -- I'm still pretty new to F#, though I've worked a bit in Haskell. It seems your 39.2k rep is well deserved, many thanks!